# Apache access log shows 2 IPs

Tags: php, apache

I have a website and i was looking at the apache access log and its something like:

> www.my-website.com:80 **10.xx.xx.xxx 24.114.xx.xxx** - -
>   [25/Aug/2014:23:59:51 +0000] 0 "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 8915 "-"
>   "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 7_1_2 like Mac OS X)
>   AppleWebKit/537.51.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0 Mobile/xxx7
>   Safari/9537.53"

As you can see it shows two ips, I checked the 2nd IP is my device's public IP from which I am accessing the website. What is the first IP for?

When I try to get the IP of client accessing the site using PHP function calls like `$ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');`  it always shows me the 1st IP.

What is the 1st IP? Please help me understand this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the full Apache config for your site, and see what it's using for its `LogFormat` directive.  It will either be a nickname for a common format, or a customized format which will list the fields that are included in the log.

Custom formats: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats